# How to decode URL in objective c iphone?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, url, decode

I was wondering if there is a method to decode a string that is in URL

encoded format?

this is my URL i want to decode it but i dont understand how to do this i tried multiple

ways

http://www.demii.com/demo/dooponz/admin/index.php/chat/new_message/4/1/you/2%2C7

but didn't get the right response

Please anyone can help me out of this,

how can i decode this url i dont need % sign.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By using the NSString method `-(NSString *)stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`

Ex:

```
NSString *unencodedUrlString = [@"http://www.demii.com/demo/dooponz/admin/index.php/chat/new_message/4/1/you/2%2C7" stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Has been deprecated since iOS 9

Answer (score 1):

Here's the not deprecated method : string​By​Removing​Percent​Encoding.

`NSString *unencodedUrlString = [yourString string​By​Removing​Percent​Encoding];`